# SharePoint Online: ?toolpaneview=2 stopped working

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-developer

Today we noticed our lists have been upgraded to the new UI/Version of SPO (I'm assuming it was upgraded to SP16).

With this upgrade the ? `toolpaneview=2` URL have stopped working on the newitem, edititem and dispitem.aspx pages for lists.

Does anyone know how to access these pages in Edit mode with this new version of SPO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it is just like the new experience in the document libraries, list experience hasn't hit our tenant yet, go to the list's advanced settings and tell it to use the classic experience.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The list forms in the new experience dont seem to have any web part zones as the case is with the classic list forms. New list forms are built using `Knockout`, `react` etc.. The old style table layout has also been replaced with `div` and `ul` based layout.

Answer (score 0):

If the the user has persmission to edit the pages then here is **quick hack** to edit pages.

1. Press **F12** to open brwosers developer tools on the page you want to edit
2. Type `ChangeLayoutMode(false)` at console and press Enter.

Your page will open in Edit mode.